# PySpark JdbcUtils relation between Catalyst and JDBC Types

Tags: jdbc, pyspark

While writing a Dataframe as a MySQL table in PySpark I am facing a `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column` error, which means that the data exceed the maximum value admitted by MySQL `TEXT` type.

As seen in [JdbcUtils.getCommonJDBCType method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L154), `TEXT` is the default JDBC type for Catalyst's `StringType`:

```
def getCommonJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = {
    dt match {
      ...
      case StringType => Option(JdbcType("TEXT", java.sql.Types.CLOB))
      ...
    }
  }
```

I was wondering, is there any way of manually defining a relation between a Catalyst Type (StringType) and a JDBC type (LONGTEXT) using the `write.jdbc` method of a Dataframe?

Comment: Neither `TEXT` nor `LONGTEXT` is a JDBC type, they are MySQL datatypes. JDBC types are the types defined in [`java.sql.Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see, thank you. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know Spark, but if I were you, I'd check if there is a way to override this (eg in something like a dialect).

Comment: The problem is I am using the python implementation of Spark, so extending original Scala code is not an option.